# Sending one email for multiple changes in sheet

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

I have created below script which works fine: It sends one e-mail for each cell that has been edited.

Meanwhile, what I want is one mail being sent for each change on a row, i.e. modifying cells C1, C2 and C3 should result in one mail sent.

```js
function emailReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var recipient = "****@****.ca";
  var subject = 'Update to '+ sheet.getName();
  var body = sheetName + ' has been updated.  Visit     '+ ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes.'; 
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  if (sheetName == "Radio recordings")
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "****@******.ca",
        subject: "Enregistrement ",
        htmlBody: "<h1>Planification d'enregistrement</h1> <br><p>Aller à l'address suivant pour planifier l'enregistrement <br><br>" + ss.getUrl() + "<br><br> Merci<br><br>*****</p>",
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code sends the email, but how is it triggered? I assume you have setup an "on edit trigger" for this code. Also if you can give more details on who and how user can modify the sheet it would be helpful. PS: Please remove your email ID and any other forms of personal info in the code before submitted, to avoid spams. Especially if people incorporate you code without removing your email, you might end up getting a lot of emails :)

Comment: The document is opened by 10 or 15 other user. they all have permision to edit cells.  It is a working document that is populated during the day and from a template will be archived at the end of the day a new one will be recreated for the next day.  Also Yes it's triggered by an onEdit.